# Ajax PHP Search, Query result instead of XML

Tags: php

I'm following the [tutorial from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp) on ajax search and I'm having some trouble tweaking the code. The structure I got is:

**search.php** - ( *Where the search terms ?q=search will output a result as* `echo $result` )

**livesearch.php** - ( *Where it will exchange information between search.php and search.html* )

**search.html** - ( *Where it contains java script and what not* )

How can I, please, make it instead of grabbing information from XML, grab from the output string in search.php?  In other words, if the HTTP request is "livesearch.php?q=searchTerm", I want to output "searchTerm."

Comment: Sara, I would recommend using a tutorial from somewhere other than w3cschools.

Comment: @david Yeah I've seen _worse_. But I know there are much better ones too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial on the site is providing you with that answer: `responseText`. If you set that to an element's `innerHTML`, of course, it'll display as HTML.

I would suggest not reinventing the wheel, though, and use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org), or some other JS framework for that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

In **livesearch.php**, just replace:

```
echo $response;
```

with:

```
echo $_GET['q'];
```

---

All URL query string params (GET params) are stored in the `$_GET` [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).  Additionally, If you want the *entire* query string, access it with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.